# How can I write a query to get a list of users who have registered in the last 24 hours?

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to use PHP to generate a query that fetches the number of users who have registered in the last 24 hours.

Based on the code for the "who's online" block:

```
$authenticated_count = db_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.uid) FROM {sessions} s WHERE s.timestamp >= :timestamp AND s.uid > 0", array(':timestamp' => $interval))->fetchField();
```

I modified it as follows (based on this [old D6 Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4030877):

```
$users_registered = db_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.uid) FROM {users} u WHERE u.created >= :timestamp AND u.uid > 0", array(':timestamp' => ($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - 86400)));
```

However, this results in an error:

> Notice: Object of class DatabaseStatementBase could not be converted
>   to int in format_plural() (line 1801 of
>   /var/www/om/includes/common.inc).

I'm not great with SQL, so a brief explanation of where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you aren't doing anything wrong; it's just that the object you will get back from `db_query()` in your case is not something you can use as is.

Invoke `->fetchField()` method after `db_query()` so that Drupal's DB API returns you one single value.

Use this:

```
$users_registered = db_query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.uid) FROM {users} u WHERE u.created >= :timestamp AND u.uid > 0", array(':timestamp' => (REQUEST_TIME - 86400)));
```

Also, use `REQUEST_TIME` constant to get current timestamp.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure - glad it helped.